# ASP .NET WebApi 2 sending Json To api with class that has some

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, web

API method receive an object of this class:

```
    public class TestModel
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _list;
    private IEnumerable<string> _list2;

    public IEnumerable<string> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list2 = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List2
    {
        get { return _list2; }
        set { _list2 = value; }
    }

}
```

I know that it might looks weird, it is ofc. But inside a C# Code if you will set a new value for any List or List2 you will always set a List2 to a new value. However, if you use that with API:

The API Method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Test(TestModel test)
    {
        return Ok(test);
    }
```

Request JSON:

```
{
    "List":["asdas", "asdasd"],
    "List2":["qwe", "qwe"],
}
```

You wuld receive such a response:

```
{
"list": null,
"list2": [
    "asdas",
    "asdasd",
    "qwe",
    "qwe"
  ]
}
```

I know that this is not a normal, but I found that by accident and I'm very curious about that how it happens as I use readonly IEnumerable lists and still it's merging two lists into one - why? 
I'm pretty sure that it comes to serialization, but still cannot guess how it works.

Will be very thankfull for anybody who can explain that and satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<string> List
{
    get { return _list; }
    set { _list = value; }
}
```

You are using `_list2` variable to set the property `List`. That's why value of `List` set to `List2`.

Comment: I know that. You haven't answered my question.
Please look at api response where the api method not just set the value of List to List2 but merge two lists.